# Issue with Formulas not showing data after Row insert

Tags: excel-formula

Hi I have 2 sheets in Excel.  One sheet, called DATA, has questions such as :"How did you find the room" with answers like "Excellent".

On the 2nd sheet I have a formula

```
=IF(Data!$I$4="Excellent ",5,IF(Data!$I$4="Good",4,0))
```

I have copied this formula to row 10.

If I add extra rows to the DATA sheet, the formulas in the 2nd sheet do not appear.

Comment: A good question is what is the current contents of cell I4 on sheet Data?  Try Typing in "Good" there.

Answer (score 0):

You are using absolute reference.  Try removing the $.  When the $ is present it prevents the row or column number from changing as the formula is copied.  Place the cursor in a cell reference or select a range reference and press F4 repeatedly and it will cycle through the $A$1, A$1, $A1, A1 options.

Also note you have a space after "Excellent ".  Matching for "Excellent" is not the same as "Excellent ".  You may want to change your formula to:

```
=IF(Trim(Data!$I$4)="Excellent",5,IF(Trim(Data!$I$4)="Good",4,0))
```

Trim will remove excess spaces between words and only leave 1 space in between.

If you have more than just excellent in the cell and maybe something like "Excellent Job",  you might want to use the SEARCH or FIND functions in your formula.